# Problem with large MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm programming now a project with a business database over then 20M records.
This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `business` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`rdate` datetime NOT NULL,
`valid` int(1) NOT NULL,
`visible` int(1) NOT NULL,
`lockItem` int(1) NOT NULL,
`parent` int(10) NOT NULL,
`titleENG` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`state` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`zipCode` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`webAddress` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`fax` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`contact_name` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`contact_title` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`contact_gender` enum('','male','female') COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`company_employee` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`text` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`bigPic` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`keywords` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`lowerTitle` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `visible` (`visible`),
 KEY `parent` (`parent`),
 KEY `valid` (`valid`),
 KEY `titleENG` (`titleENG`),
 KEY `state` (`state`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 KEY `city` (`city`),
 KEY `keywords` (`keywords`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `titleENG_2` (`titleENG`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `lowerTitle` (`lowerTitle`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `phone` (`phone`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `city_2` (`city`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `state_2` (`state`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `business_search` (`lowerTitle`,`phone`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=12409005 ;
```

Some of my queries i'm doing via fulltext, wonder if I can use via LIKE and using lower() functions etc' but with high speed.

Can someone advice me some tips?

Comment: Can you provide examples of queries you want to optimize?

Comment: Have you tried doing any of those queries, and if so, what problems with speed have you encountered?

Comment: Example to query:
SELECT id,city,state FROM business WHERE MATCH (city) AGAINST (\'Homer\' IN BOOLEAN MODE) GROUP BY city,state LIMIT 10
takes something like 5 secounds...  but I cant using lower cases and search the same like: "homer"

Comment: what is the expected result from this query? Why you are selecting one of many possible ids? Because of the group by, it creates temporary table. Run explain to check the table. Maybe it's better yo use like '%homer%', and use index on city,state for the group by operation?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to change the collation for needed columns. For instance:

```
ALTER TABLE `business` CHANGE COLUMN `city` `city` VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NOT NULL;
```

Then you can use the same fulltext search.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need INDEX on id as you already have one
- MyISAM is faster with char-s than with varchar-s
- If you don't use bin collation, you don't need lower(). Use case insensitive collation, if you really don't need it case-sensitive
- Check your queries and indexes. Maybe compound indexes on multiple columns will perform better then individual indexes (and each index makes writting slower)
- What is your write/read ratio? If you have a lot of insert/updates, you have to minimize the number of indexes, as well consider migrating to InnoDB
- Offload the full-text search to Sphinx, Solr or any third party search engine (or build full-text index on your own)
- visible index seems unnecessary - the value is either 0 or 1, and this means index is not effective, and I'm pretty sure you have no query that filters only on 'visible'